# What's the attention model used in tfjs-examples/date-conversion-attention?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've been looking at tfjs examples and trying to learn about seq2seq models. During the process, I've stumbled upon the [date-conversion-attention](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/date-conversion-attention) example.

It's a great example but what kind of attention mechanism is being used in the example? There is no info in `Readme` file. Can somebody point me to the paper that describes the attention that's being used here?

Link to attention part:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/908ee32750ba750a14d15caeb53115e2d3dda2b3/date-conversion-attention/model.js#L102-L119

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer.
The attention model used in the `date-conversion-attention` uses the dot product alignment score and it's described in `Effective Approaches to Attention-based Neural Machine Translation`. Link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04025.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have twisted my head around this sample for some hours now, and this what I have concluded so far:

The encoder looks at the full input, one character-embedding for each lstm-step.  The decoder expects a time-shifted copy of the output as its input -starting with a special character.  The output (target strings) are provided as-is to the decoder during training.  During evaluation, one character is predicted at the time, passing the prediction back into the decoder for the next character.

The decoder does not see the input, but it receives the encoder's final step output as its initial state.  This state initialisation tells the decoder how to produce it's outputs, something like an encoded description of the date-format to work on (I assume).

The LSTM's output, one for each step (=character of input or output), from the encoder and decoder are then dot product'ed and normalised with softmax.  This dot-product is the **attention matrix** - basically a highlight of the activations from the encoder and the decoder.  For the attention heatmap to light up for the given next character, the decoder must have output'ed something that "matches" the encoder's outputs.  The attention matrix is not learned weights or biases, its just a product of the encoder and decoder's outputs.

Finally this attention matrix is dot product'ed with the full encoder input and concatenated with the decoder output - to allow the final dense layers to decode the attention mappings and "read" the right values from the encoder output.

In the prediction process, only the last character is read from the prediction.  Possibly because the previous predictions might be unstable?

I read the excellent book: [Deep Learning with JavaScript Neural networks in TensorFlow.js](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-javascript) The book explains the examples one by one and adds lots of extra documentation.  But I don't think they explain the general architecture very well, for this sample - only the details.