# Luong's Concat Alignment Score Issue

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've been trying to understand how attention mechanism works. Currently looking at [tfjs-examples/date-conversion-attention](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/date-conversion-attention) example. I've [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059272/whats-the-attention-model-used-in-tfjs-examples-date-conversion-attention) that in the example the `dot product alignment score` (from [`Effective Approaches to Attention-based Neural Machine Translation`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04025.pdf)) is being used.

So this expression [image] is represented as

```js
let attention = tf.layers.dot({axes: [2, 2]}).apply([decoder, encoder]);
```

in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/908ee32750ba750a14d15caeb53115e2d3dda2b3/date-conversion-attention/model.js#L102).
The decoder (`h_t`) has a shape of [10,64] and the encoder (`h_s`) is [12,64] so the result will have a shape of [10,12]. So far so good.

Now I'm trying to implement the `concat alignment score`, which looks like this
[image].

So the first thing to do is to concatenate the `h_t` and `h_s`. However, they have different shapes so I don't know how to proceed. Should I reshape somehow the tensors? If so, what would be the shape?

I've been googling around to find out how other people do this and found [this](https://github.com/gabrielloye/Attention_Seq2seq-Translation/blob/master/main.ipynb).

```py
#For concat scoring, decoder hidden state and encoder outputs are concatenated first
out = torch.tanh(self.fc(decoder_hidden+encoder_outputs))
```

But this doesn't seem right as they sum the values instead of concatenating.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** Here is the model summary:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output shape         Param #     Receives inputs
==================================================================================================
input1 (InputLayer)             [null,12]            0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_Embedding1 (Embedding [null,12,64]         2240        input1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input2 (InputLayer)             [null,10]            0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_LSTM1 (LSTM)               [null,12,64]         33024       embedding_Embedding1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_Embedding2 (Embedding [null,10,64]         832         input2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoderLast (GetLastTimestepLay [null,64]            0           lstm_LSTM1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_LSTM2 (LSTM)               [null,10,64]         33024       embedding_Embedding2[0][0]
                                                                 encoderLast[0][0]
                                                                 encoderLast[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dot_Dot1 (Dot)                  [null,10,12]         0           lstm_LSTM2[0][0]
                                                                 lstm_LSTM1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention (Activation)          [null,10,12]         0           dot_Dot1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
context (Dot)                   [null,10,64]         0           attention[0][0]
                                                                 lstm_LSTM1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_Concatenate1 (Conca [null,10,128]        0           context[0][0]
                                                                 lstm_LSTM2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_TimeDistribute [null,10,64]         8256        concatenate_Concatenate1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_TimeDistribute [null,10,13]         845         time_distributed_TimeDistributed1
==================================================================================================
Total params: 78221
Trainable params: 78221
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, for the `tf.layers.dot` to work, both inputs should have the same shape.

To perform a concatenation, you can use tf.concat`([h_t, h_s])`. The new shape will depend on the axis over which the concatenation is performed.

Lets suppose that both `h_t` and `h_s` have the shape `[a, b]`, if the concatenation is done over the axis 0, then the new shape would be `[2a, b]` and if it is done over the axis 1, the resulting shape would be `[a, 2b]`

Then you can apply the `tf.tanh` to the input or create a customize layer that does it for you.

Update:

Since the tf.layers.dot is performed over 3d data who happen not to match on the second axis (axis = 1), the concatenation can be done only on that axis and the resulting shape would be `[ 1, 10 + 12, 64 ]`

Comment: > First thing, for the tf.layers.dot to work, both inputs should have the same shape.


In this case I getting even more confused. (I've updated the original question and added the model summary.) Looking at the model it says that the `dot_Dot1 (Dot)` receives as input `lstm_LSTM1` and `lstm_LSTM2` whose shapes are [null, 12,64] and [null, 10, 64]. Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: It is working in this case because it is performed over 3d tensors, the batchsize that was not indicated previously. The concat can be done over the second axis, axis = 1. The resulting shape will be [1, 22, 64]

Comment: You are right, I didn't specify the batchsize. Sorry for that. However, I'm still confused with the concat. I mean, the `dot score` make sense to me as I'm performing dot product along the LSTM features of encoder and decoder. This means that I'm "mixing" their features into one ([batch_size, 10, 12]) tensor. However, in `concat score`, if I stack them into a [batch_size, 22, 64] there is no "mix" between the features. So it doesn't feel right to me... but again I'm still learning so I might be missing something

Comment: I can't tell the mathematical reason behind it. Maybe you would need to read the paper where the concat alignement is used

Comment: I've read it like 10 times already. But the paper doesn't explain the reasoning behind these ops. The authors just said that they've tested 3 different score functions and that's it. Anyway, thank you very much for your time.